# Loop, Read stops after one record with GUI (doesn't loop)

Tags: loops, user-interface, autohotkey

I have a script for entering records in our system that was originally working fine with a MsgBox, but I added a GUI to show the record entry. Now the script stops after the first record.

In the example below I've stripped out all of the actions and record lines to help make this easier to parse, but I've kept in all the important stuff and tested this version of the script.

```
Loop, read, C:\_AutoHotKey\AA_test.txt
{
    StringSplit, LineArray, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%

    aaduedate   := LineArray1
    aauniqueid  := LineArray2
    aaprefix    := LineArray3
    aasequence  := LineArray4
    aadescript  := LineArray5
    aaelig      := LineArray6

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Use these to test the file match in the Input File.
;Remove surrounding comments and surround the rest of the script up to the last brace.
    SendInput, Prefix: %aaprefix% {enter}
    SendInput, Sequence: %aasequence% {enter}
    SendInput, Description: %aadescript% {enter}
    SendInput, Eligibility: %aaelig% {enter}
    SendInput, ID Card: %aaidcard% {enter}
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Pop-up validation menu
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y380 w100 h30 , &Submit
Gui, Add, Button, x362 y380 w100 h30 , &Cancel
Gui, Font, S14 CDefault, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, x152 y10 w210 h30 +Center, Is the entry correct?
Gui, Font, S10 CDefault, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, x102 y40 w90 h20 , %aaprefix%
Gui, Add, Text, x102 y70 w130 h20 , %aaelig%
Gui, Add, Text, x312 y70 w30 h20 , %aadescript%
Gui, Add, Text, x432 y70 w30 h20 , %aaidcard%
Gui, Font, S8 CDefault, Verdana
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y380 w230 h40 +Center, Click Submit/press S to continue. Click cancel to stop script.
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator 4.0
Gui, Show, x9 y250 h428 w480, Auto Action Validation
Return

ButtonCancel: 
ExitApp

ButtonSubmit: 
Gui, Submit ; 
    MouseMove, 630,55
    Sleep, 100
    SendInput, {Click 630,55}
    SendInput ^S

Return

}
```

The buttons do work and clicking Submit will send the MouseMove and SendInput. But after that it just stops and doesn't load the next record in the text file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a return command within the loop.

This exits the program

See this example.
This loop should run 5 times, but the return 
command stops it after the first run.

```
Loop, 5
{
  msgbox, %A_Index%
  return
}
```

Comment: The problem with this kind of programming approach is that if you leave out the
*return* command, the loop doesn't pause. So that doesn't work either. A better approach would be write a function
that reads just on (the next) item from the list and types that. Then you can open the GUI out of the loop and call this function every time an entry is confirmed or not. This is a bit tricky. If you are a beginner, you might have more success if you open a message box with a yes/no button within the loop.

Comment: Ah. Shoot. Well, I am a beginner but, I also need to have the record display for the user to verify. So, it looks like I'll be learning how to do the GUI out of the loop. 

Thanks! (If you have any tips on what I should look for in the help, that'd be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: I've figured out how to make this work and still get the GUI to display the record. I took the Submit and Cancel buttons out of the GUI and brought the MsgBox back in. If the MsgBox evaluates to yes then it destroys the GUI.

My next comment has the code in it along with a little thing to move the message box out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by removing the submit button from the GUI and moving it to a MsgBox.

The GUI is basically the same but the Submit and Cancel lines have been removed along with the returns and all logic following it.

Next, a MsgBox was added to confirm the data. This now uses the GUI to display the contents of the record and the MsgBox to confirm and move on to the next record.

Also, there's some code I stole (and don't really understand) that moves the MsgBox so that it doesn't block the data entry screen in the receiving app.

Here's the new code that replaces everything after Gui, Show, x9...

```
OnMessage(0x44, "WM_COMMNOTIFY")
MsgBox 4, AA Entry, Would you like to continue? (press Yes or No)

WM_COMMNOTIFY(wParam) {
    if (wParam = 1027) { ; AHK_DIALOG
        Process, Exist
                DetectHiddenWindows, On
        if WinExist("ahk_class #32770 ahk_pid " . ErrorLevel) {
            WinGetPos,,, w
            WinMove, 90, 650
        }
    }
    }
;If the user responds yes, then close the Gui (Destroy) and enter the record
IfMsgBox Yes
    {
        Gui destroy
        Sleep, 100
}
    else
        ExitApp

}
```

Thanks, and I hope this is helpful to someone.